# How to insert a formatted string into a specific buffer?

Tags: buffers, insert

I am looking for a way to insert a formatted text into a specific buffer (not the active buffer).

As it seems to me, the only way to do so is to use a snippet as shown below:

```
(insert (propertize (format-time-string "%H:%M:%S")
                    'face
                    '(:height 4.0 :inverse-video t)))
```

The above inserts it into the active/current buffer.

There are ways to insert strings to a specific buffer but then they do not support formatting.

I am starting to wonder if what I intend to do is even possible...

Comment: Try using the `with-current-buffer` macro.

Comment: Looks like what I need, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An example of what you are trying to do is contained in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Current-Buffer.html).
You need either `with-current-buffer` or `save-current-buffer`:

```
(with-current-buffer destination-buffer
  (insert (propertize (format-time-string "%H:%M:%S")
                      'face '(:height 4.0 :inverse-video t))))
```